# SharePoint error whan adding user as site owner

Tags: sharepoint, hresult

I have a MOSS 2007 site which I'm an admin for. In the 'People and Groups' area for a site, I'm trying to add a user as a site owner. On the 'Add User' page, I add the name of the user and click 'OK', after which I get this totally useless error:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E37
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.UpdateMembers(String
>   bstrUrl, Guid& pguidScopeId, Int32
>   lGroupID, Int32 lGroupOwnerId, Object&
>   pvarArrayAdd, Object& pvarArrayAddIds,
>   Object& pvarArrayLoginsRemove, Object&
>   pvarArrayIdsRemove, Boolean
>   bSendEmail)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.UpdateMembers(String
>   bstrUrl, Guid& pguidScopeId, Int32
>   lGroupID, Int32 lGroupOwnerId, Object&
>   pvarArrayAdd, Object& pvarArrayAddIds,
>   Object& pvarArrayLoginsRemove, Object&
>   pvarArrayIdsRemove, Boolean
>   bSendEmail)

I've used WinDbg to see if I could get a more meaningful error message, but nothing useful came out of that. I also ran an SQL profile on the calls used, but again, nothing really conclusive was shown.

If it helps, this site was recently restored from a backup performed on another server. The site itself is running fine after being restored, it's just this bit which seems to be broken.

Can anyone help me with this?

Cheers.
Jas.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like maybe stsadm -backup and -restore were used to move the site from another farm?  This used to cause a variety of hard-to-debug issues, and was only addressed as of the April Cumulative Update (released right after SP2).  Do you know if both your servers have the April Cumulative Update installed?

Comment: Yes the site was backed up and then restored via stsadm - from one server onto another (took a bit of hacking to get the restore working!). Neither of the sites have any SP's installed. Updating to SP2 is a bit tricky in this scenario, but it sounds like a possible solution, since everything else I've tried has failed. I'll see if I can make any progress on this.